# Unable to show image using ajax for secured API (Basic Auth)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to show images which is fetch using server API which is secured using Basic Auth and i am getting error while loading image into a view.

```
<head>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://myurl.com", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa('test:test123'));
xhr.onload = function () {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();

</script>
</head>


<div id="image" style="width: 430px; height: 430px;"></div>

 and i am getting below error.

 Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

[image]

Comment: what is the backend your are using

Comment: API using spring

Comment: `https://myurl.com` is the domain this script is running on?

Comment: nooo its just example url

Comment: This is because when we add authorization header the browser send an option request before the get . so you have to handle that option request in server

Comment: But using android and Postman its working fine for web we need to add anything else ?

Comment: yes it is needed when we are using a web browser

Comment: i don't know springs , but i do this in laravel by adding a preflight middleware

Comment: Can you give m any reference about this.

Answer (score 0):

The browser sends an OPTIONS call to server before the initial request is done. 
It is checking if you are allowed to do this call, if this call/endpoint exists and several things like this.

Also check: https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png

If you are using Spring Boot you should allow OPTIONS calls in your CORS configuration. 
Example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic()
    .and()
        .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll() // allow CORS option calls 
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
}
```